# Inflater - getting themed context does not work

Tags: android, android-theme, layout-inflater, android-context

In my base dialog class I use something like following:

```
IDialogThemeProvider themeProvider = Functions.tryConvert(IDialogThemeProvider.class, getActivity());
if (themeProvider != null && themeProvider.getDialogThemeResId() != null)
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), themeProvider.getDialogThemeResId()));
```

So afterwards I have an inflater with the correct themed context. Afterwards I use this inflater in two ways:

1. `inflater.inflate(...)` => this works perfectly fine and uses the provided theme
2. `TextView tv = new TextView(inflater.getContext())` => this does NOT work, this uses the default theme and not the one used in the inflater

How can I solve that? I probably can hand on the themed context, but actually, I should be able to get this context somehow from the inflater...

Answer (score 0):

1. I now tried using the 3 arg constructor of a view with the themed context... => does not work
2. I tried using the themed context directly => does not work

Only solution that works is, inflate a view from xml. So for my use cases, I created a checkbox.xml and a edittext.xml and use those layouts. That should at least always work...